# find unique file ID through powershell

Tags: powershell, uniqueidentifier

After modifying an existing file I would like to find out if the software used to modify the file created and saved the new file (discarding the old one) or changed the original file.

Currently I'm using powershell with [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6):

```
Get-ChildItem D: -Force | Select-Object Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Length
```

This only works if the software in question didn't reapply the orginal `CreationTime` in the new file. If it did ([like e.g. Excel does when editing existing files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814068/description-of-the-way-that-excel-saves-files)) the result would look the same regardless if the original file was modified or a new file created. I figured I could use the [object identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/distributed-link-tracking-and-object-identifiers) to do that, but I didn't manage to implement it with power shell show it shows the object ID of the file, did I overlook something in [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo) or do I have to use a different command altogether?

Using `-Property *` to show all properties, kind of tells me that I'm on the wrong track altogether (it doesn't give me any usable property at least not for my use case):

```
Get-ChildItem D: -Force | Select-Object -Property *
```

I event tried the [ID property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) which, of course, didn't work for file objects. Theoretically I could get a file ID from NTFS's USN journal, but in my use case unfortunately the journal is deactivated on the drive containing the file.

Comment: I found a few other approaches in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052477/uniquely-identify-files-folders-in-ntfs-even-after-move-rename, couldn't get any of them to work though - at least so far

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this 'ID'? As you found, programs can just mess with the file attributes like date created, so without some filesystem level journal, I'm not sure there's any functional difference between 'updating' a file, and writing a new one.

If you want to go by file contents, you could use Get-FileHash to get a unique hash for the data of the file.

Comment: @Josh as I said in my first sentence, I'd like to check which programs modify an existing file and which programs create a new one (discarding the original one). Not sure how a check sum would help in this case, since the file will be changed?!

Comment: @Josh PS. one possible use case (or functional difference) would be to see if the original file could be recovered from deleted temp files found on the drive after excitedly saving a new version.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the NTFS File ID. There is no PowerShell native cmdlet, but there is this command:

```
fsutil file queryfileid <filename>
```

Microsoft Office is an example of software that behaves as you describe -- whenever you hit "save" to modify an existing file, it first writes the data out to a brand new file, then deletes the old one and renames the new one to have the same name as the old one. As a result, the File ID changes.

If you try this with a text file, then open, change, and save it, the File ID does not change, indicating that Notepad writes to the same file.

You could probably observe this behaviour in action by having Sysinternals Process Monitor (available from Microsoft's download site) running; it should show the individual file creates, writes, etc.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer... I hope I still remember the original Problem. I'll try the solution and let you know. Fell free to send a reminder in case I forget!